# Only display a checkbox on child nodes with Kendo Treeview

Tags: kendo-treeview

I have the following situation, where i have a parent node with a number of nested child nodes. Only the parent node should have a checkbox, the only example i have found is where only the child nodes have a checkbox. Is this possible using kendo templates?

http://dojo.telerik.com/@AndyBeeby/IKoHi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template: "#if (item.Element=== 'aValue' ) {# <input type='checkbox' #if(item.checked) { #checked# }# />#}"`

Using a template to apply the check boxes to items that have a certain value.